# Why sprite twitches?

Tags: java, libgdx

Wrote a function that calculates the coordinates of a sprite that moves in a circle.
Well, the formula is elementary

x = x0 + R * cos (t * a + a0)

y = y0 + R * sin (t * a + a0)

The function looks like this

```
    public void pointDefinition(float delta)
  {
    sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2+(85*(float)Math.cos(i*delta)), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2+(85*(float)Math.sin(i*delta)));
    i = i + 0.5;
  }
```

I call it in render ()
In the end, everything works, but the sprite somehow nervously twitches.
Here is a video that demonstrates this.

[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Dfedd8dczft5PV3RbUzAKQg1a2aukx-/view?usp=sharing)

The following content is sent to the delta variable.

```
pointDefinition(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 60f));
```

I can not understand the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should increment `i` with `delta` instead of using `delta` as a parameter in the formula:

```java
public void pointDefinition(float delta)
{
    sprite.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) + (85 * (float)Math.cos(i)), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2) + (85 * (float)Math.sin(i)));
    i = i + delta;
}
```

After all, `delta` will have different values each time, which is what is causing your little icon to move back sometimes.

To understand what is happening, imagine these two iterations:

#### First iteration

1. `i` = `2`
2. `delta` = `0.0025`

In this case, `i * delta` will be **`0.005`**.

#### Second iteration

2. `i` = `2.5`
3. `delta` = `0.0017`

In this case, `i * delta` will be **`0.00425`**.

As you can see, the value of `i * delta`, which you are using as the parameter of `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()`, decreased in the second iteration, causing your icon to jitter.

To keep the animation consistent, it is important to make sure the parameter you pass to these two functions (`Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()`) only increases with each iteration!